# When ArcMap Rest Create Replica command is used, what is returned?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, json, replication, error-001558

I can access a feature service, and initiate a *create replica* command - but i am not sure how to digest what is returned.

Example code below:

```
# Setting up the POST request
create_replica_form_data = {'replicaName':'traggatmot_pull',
                     'layers':0,
                     'layerQueries':'',
                     'geometry':'',
                     'geometryType':'esriGeometryEnvelope',
                     'inSR':'',
                     'replicaSR':'',
                     'transportType':'esriTransportTypeEmbedded',
                     'returnAttachments':'false',
                     'returnAttachmentsDataByUrl':'true',
                     'async':'false',
                     'syncModel':'perLayer',
                     'attachmentsSyncDirection':'none',
                     'replicaOptions':'',
                     'dataFormat':'json',
                     'f':'pjson',
                     'token':token}
    
    
r = requests.post("http://services3.arcgis.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/arcgis/rest/services/XXXXXXXXXXXX/FeatureServer/createReplica", data=create_replica_form_data)
    
with open("layer_pull.json", 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(r.json(), outfile)

arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("layer_pull.json", os.path.join("layer_pull.gdb", "layer_pull"))
```

Error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file 'sades_pull_01_12_2016.json'. 
Failed to execute (JSONToFeatures).
```

This error seems to suggest that the JSON object returned by the CreateReplica request is not in the format that ArcMap is expect.  Here is a snapshot of the beginning:

[image]

Is this a GDB in JSON format?  How do I get this file into a GDB?

Comment: I just realized I accidentally posted this on the wrong site - should be on gis.stackexchange.